# Ubuntu 18.04 how to input Chinese tone marks? Hanyu pinyin is missing

Tags: ibus, input-language, chinese, pinyin

I am trying to have the ability to input Chinese tones directly into text editor in Ubuntu 18.04. I have installed ibus-pinyin and ibus-m17n packages but I cannot find in Region&Language input picker the `hanyu pinyin` input method, there is only Chinese, Chinese (Bopomofo), Chinese (Intelligent Pinyin), two WuBi variants and that's it.

In here https://askubuntu.com/a/735139/886864 or https://askubuntu.com/a/728506/886864 it is said it should have Chinese (hanyu pinyin (m17n)) but I cannot find it.

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to install something else in 18.04?

Comment: Reboot and see if it shows up after that.

Comment: well... it worked, I cna now see loads of different options including hanyu. Thank you :) I feel sorry for myself for not trying this step... If you'll make an answer I can accept it :)

Comment: Great! Honestly I think it's best that you simply delete the question. That 'answer' wouldn't be of general interest anyway.

Comment: On the contrary, it does not say in the linked sources that I need to reboot. This might cause a headache for someone too in the future :) Especially since it seems that Chinese (Intelligent Pinyin) option shows up after you install the packages so there is no indication that rebooting might do anything.

Comment: Well, when you install new input methods, in this case `ibus-m17n`, it's a general thing that a relogin/reboot is needed before the new method(s) will be recognized in the settings. If you think it's motivated, please fell free to submit an answer yourself. It's perfectly fine to answer your own question, and in a couple of days you'll be able to accept it too.

Comment: You are the hero in this question and I am not stealing your hard earned kudos ;) Yes I think it is a valid question, not everyone understands Ubuntu so well. Very often when you install updates they work immediately without the need for a reboot and like I mentioned - some options did appear immediately after installing ibuc-m17n. If you do not want to make an answer then let's just leave it like it is. Hopefully it will help someone though it does feel unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

The comments suggest to restart the system.

Actually, there is no need to do that.

Just restart `ibus` as follows:

```
~$ ibus restart
```