# Compose key: how to type all pinyin tone marks?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, chinese, compose-key, pinyin

I have the following input methods set up on Ubuntu 20 LTS: English (US), English (Dvorak), Chinese (Intelligent Pinyin), Chinese (hanyu pinyin (m17n)).

I would like to type pinyin with all its available tone marks **with the Compose Key**, without using the specific input method `hanyu pinyin (m17n)`. Only some of the possible tone marks seem to work with the compose key, and good documentation on this is hard to find or doesn't exist.

**Pinyin Tone Marks**

In the following examples, replace `x` with any of the base characters: `a`, `e`, `i`, `o`, `u`

- The 1st tone is the `macron`: `¯`,
  typed with `compose` + `-` + `x`
- The 2nd tone is the `acute`: `´`,
  typed with `compose` + `'` + `x`
- The 3rd tone is the `caron`: `ˇ` (note, `caron` is different from `breve`),
  typed with `compose` + `<` + `x` (`<` is `shift` + `,`)
- The 4th tone is the `grave`: `` ` ``,
  typed with `compose` + `` ` `` + `x`

**Actually**, it's more complicated than that, because there's one more "base chracter": `ü`, so in pinyin these sounds are also available: `ǖ`, `ǘ`, `ǚ`, `ǜ`. These can be combined with adding more modifiers to the compose key, `ǘ` can be produced with `compose` + `'` + `"` + `u`.

When trying all combinations, some of them work, some don't:

```
1st tone, ¯, macron, supports all but ǖ
 ā: compose - a
 ē: compose - e
 ī: compose - i
 ō: compose - o
 ū: compose - u
 ǖ: ?

2nd tone, ´, acute, supports all
 á: compose ' a
 é: compose ' e
 í: compose ' i
 ó: compose ' o
 ú: compose ' u
 ǘ: compose ' " u

3rd tone, ˇ, caron, only supports e
 ǎ: ?
 ě: compose < e
 ǐ: ?
 ǒ: ?
 ǔ: ?
 ǚ: ?

4th tone, `, grave, supports all
 à: compose ` a
 è: compose ` e
 ì: compose ` i
 ò: compose ` o
 ù: compose ` u
 ǜ: compose ` " u
```

**My questions**

0. Should this actually work? Should I file a bug report? If so; where's the source repo? Who maintains the compose key?
1. Is it possible to type all pinyin tone marks with the Compose Key? The missing combinations are: `ǖ`, `ǎ`, `ǐ`, `ǒ`, `ǔ`, `ǚ`.
2. Is it possible to add custom key sequences to the compose key (with a specific dotfile in my homedir for example)? This answer doesn't seem to work since Ubuntu 19: https://askubuntu.com/a/71335/872681

What I do ***not*** want:

- Yet another input method for just the pinyin marks, as described in the Hanyu Pinyin input in this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/728506/872681
  (I've got this working, it's just not as comfortable as using the compose key.)
- Use any form of online editor such as: https://www.pinyin-editor.com
- Use a point-and-click application like the Character Map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not on Ubuntu but since on Manjaro I had the same characters missing, maybe this will help you:

```
ǖ: compose _ ü

ǎ: compose c a
ǒ: compose c o
ǔ: compose c u
ǚ: compose c ü
```

There are other combinations to choose from, which you may find here:
`/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose`

You may even define your own combinations in `~/.XCompose` (you can just create it, if it's not there).

```
include "%L"

<Multi_key> <minus> <udiaeresis> : "ǖ"
<Multi_key> <less> <a> : "ǎ"
<Multi_key> <less> <i> : "ǐ"
<Multi_key> <less> <o> : "ǒ"
<Multi_key> <less> <u> : "ǔ"
<Multi_key> <less> <udiaeresis> : "ǚ"
```

`include "%L"` loads the systems compose file from `usr/share ...`.